# Change in table propagates to view automatically (postgres 9.3.14)

Tags: postgresql

I've got a view that depends on a table `foo`. If I rename table `foo` to `bar` then the view is automatically updated to depend on table `bar`.

```
Dag=> create table foo (id int);
CREATE TABLE
Dag=> create view foo_view as select id from foo;
CREATE VIEW
Dag=> \d+ foo_view
            View "public.foo_view"
Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Description
--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
id     | integer |           | plain   |
View definition:
SELECT foo.id
  FROM foo;

Dag=> alter table foo rename to bar;
ALTER TABLE
Dag=> \d+ foo_view
            View "public.foo_view"
Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Description
--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
id     | integer |           | plain   |
View definition:
SELECT bar.id
  FROM bar;
```

Is there any way to disable this behavior? My intent is to update table foo by populating a staging table `foo_stage`. Once `foo_stage` is populated I intend to swap out `foo` for `foo_stage` like this:

```
alter table foo rename to foo_tmp;
alter table foo_stage rename to foo;
alter table foo_tmp rename to foo_stage;
```

The problem here is that I would have to drop my view and redefine it every time I update a table it depends on. This becomes a pain to manage if I have a bunch of meta-data tables that get updated many times per day and may each have several views that depend on them.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but perhaps a [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) statement would suffice as an alternative (if this feature can't be turned off)

Comment: In instead of renaming and swapping update the table inside a transaction so the updates will only be seen when commited.